# How can I connect extention wires to this 3-pin 8mm LED strip?

Tags: wiring, led, soldering

I have two LED strips like the image below:
[image]
The strips are several feet apart. I plan on running some wires through my cabinetry to connect the two, but I'm looking for a clean way to make the connections. I don't mind soldering the wires, but the connectors are so tiny it's going to be pretty tedious and maybe not last very long.

I would love to find a connector that has wires already on it so I could just solder and shrink-wrap those wires to my extension wires. I'm not sure what that would be called to even look for though.

My primary question is what would be the cleanest way to connect these two sets of strips without having to solderer these tiny pins themselves? Do they make connectors that I can buy with extensions already built-in?

> (if you know better tags, please suggest them!)

Comment: [these](https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/132195917149) are four-pin, but there's nothing to stop you using them on three-pin strips. I expct if you look you'll find three-pin ones. I searched for "LED strip extension"

Comment: they are called dupont connectors, but if you can, I would highly suggest soldering them as those tiny pins have a lot of resistance, which would cause the non-powered end to be dimmer than the source end. The dupont cables I've seen have very high-gauge wire, ok for signal circuits but not lighting load. Also, you can pull out the male-to-male coupler shown, leaving behind the famle socket, then stick 20AWG solid core wire into the holes, which should hold tight and save the extra ohms of the coupler, all w/o solder.